# Вычисление количества високосных лет в заданном диапазоне в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, время

Задание было такое: 
Напишите программу, которая выводит в консоль все високосные годы от 1900 до 2016. Алгоритм определения високосного года найдите в интернете самостоятельно. Попробуйте усовершенствовать программу, чтобы она принимала начальный и конечный год от пользователя. Учтите ситуацию, когда начальный год оказался больше конечного.

Вот мой код. Почему-то не всегда работает, если граница диапазона - 100. Не могу понять в чем дело. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
var firstYear = prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - начало диапазона");
var secondYear = prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - конец диапазона");

var leapYearCount = 0;

function isLeapYear(year) {
  return new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1;
}

if (secondYear < firstYear) {
  for (i = secondYear; i <= firstYear; i++) {
    if (isLeapYear(i)) {
      console.log(i);
      leapYearCount++;
    }
  }
} else if (firstYear < secondYear) {
  for (i = firstYear; i <= secondYear; i++) {
    if (isLeapYear(i)) {
      console.log(i);
      leapYearCount++;
    }
  }
}

alert('В заданном диапазоне найдено ' + leapYearCount + ' високосных лет, они записаны в консоли.');
```

Comment: Не зачтут... прямо же сказано: "найтить алгоритм в Инете". И из этого логично проистекает "... и запрограммить".

Comment: A что значит `не всегда работает ` ?

Comment: Классическая ошибка, `prompt` возвращает строку. Удивительно что это вообще работает.

Comment: Решение, конечно, остроумное, но от вас явно ожидали решения с проверкой делимости на 4 и всяческими исключениями

Comment: @AlexeyTen задание в этом как раз  и заключалось, что нужно было применить prompt

Comment: @AlexeyTen  вариант с делимостью на 4 тоже есть... и работает он также хорошо, за исключением диапазона 50 - 100.

Comment: @MBo если обозначить диапазон 50 - 100, говорит, что високосных лет 0. Вообще ума не приложу в чем дело(

Comment: Данные из `prompt` нужно переводить в числа

Answer (score 0):

Вам @AlexeyTen уже подсказал -  `prompt` возвращает строку.

Преобразуйте результат `prompt` в число, например вот так.

```js
var firstYear = +prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - начало диапазона"); // преобразуем в число
var secondYear = +prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - конец диапазона"); // преобразуем в число

var leapYearCount = 0;

function isLeapYear(year) {
  return new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1;
}

if (secondYear < firstYear) {
  for (i = secondYear; i <= firstYear; i++) {
    if (isLeapYear(i)) {
      console.log(i);
      leapYearCount++;
    }
  }
} else if (firstYear < secondYear) {
  for (i = firstYear; i <= secondYear; i++) {
    if (isLeapYear(i)) {
      console.log(i);
      leapYearCount++;
    }
  }
}

alert('В заданном диапазоне найдено ' + leapYearCount + ' високосных лет, они записаны в консоли.');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Алгоритм определения високосного года найдите в интернете

Что пишут в интернетах:

**Високосный год** — Википедия.

- Год, номер которого кратен 400, — високосный;
- Остальные годы, номер которых кратен 100, — невисокосные (например, годы 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300);
- Остальные годы, номер которых кратен 4, — високосные[5].

Т.о. можно предложить такой вариант.

```js
var firstYear = +prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - начало диапазона");
var secondYear = +prompt("Пожалуйста, введите год - конец диапазона");

let leapYearCount = 0;

function isLeapYear(year) {
  if (year % 400 === 0) return true
  if (year % 100 === 0) return false
  if (year % 4 === 0) return true
  return false
}
let beg = firstYear
let end = secondYear

if (secondYear < firstYear) {
  beg = secondYear
  end = firstYear
}
for (let i = beg; i <= end; i++) {
  if (isLeapYear(i)) {
    console.log(i);
    leapYearCount++;
  }
}

alert('В заданном диапазоне найдено ' + leapYearCount + ' високосных лет, они записаны в консоли.');
```